# Creating a List64 class

Tags: c#, .net

I've decided that I need to create a 64-bit List to fulfill some of my program's needs, namely the ability to use longs as indexes. I've looked at the Mono code for implementing a List, and have come to the general conclusion that no matter what I choose, I should make a variation of IList (using longs) to work with it.

Now my question is, what do you think would be a good approach to this design? I am currently thinking of two possibilities -> since a List is just a wrapper for the Array class, I can just rewrite the List class to use giant arrays; or I can write the class to use a List of Lists to maintain and grow the data as needed. The problem with the first appears to be choosing an array that is too large, and the second is trying to make Remove() and other assorted methods work, when I'd probably need to perform massive memory copies to keep everything indexed properly. Your thoughts?

Comment: You need more than 2 billion elements in memory at once?

Comment: What is your use case for this - what problem are you trying to solve? There probably is a better approach

Comment: Have you checked to see if lists that large are actually feasible/possible?

Comment: Evolutionary programming. I could arguably have a few Terabytes of data loaded into RAM for a single evolution. But more importantly, the addressing scheme I am using kind of requires this approach. Frankly, I am surprised that MS dropped the ball on this one -> it seems like something you WOULD enable for the 64-bit .Net framework.

Comment: Do you really need Insert/Remove? If you can nix those, it will make things much saner

Comment: I'm debating it. I kind of wish it was easier to insert / remove things without compromising the index, but for now, I see that I'm going to have to suck it up and deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since arrays are limited to be indexed by int you will have to use multiples of them anyway. I'd directly go for List of List. Note that all objects in CLR are limited by 2Gb single chunk of memory for allocation.

Side notes:

- if you planning to implement true 4GB+ linear array that support insert/remove operations in the middle you simply should adjust your performace expectations - any insert or remove will be slow. At such scale having append only array maybe reasonable approach.
- if add/remove are important consider some other data structures i.e. [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). You will sacrify constant access time in most cases, but gain reasonable.
- if you arrays are sparse consider simple Dictionary instead or as backing storage.

Here is link to more detailed discussion about [large arrays](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx).

Comment: Indeed. The design of the program is such that append only is actually possible.